# MySQL subquery and join statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have written a query to fetch gender and name of the employees from  tables `e and profile` on the basis of employee id `emp` Now I have a table like:

```
gender   name
m         qwqw
f         wewe
m         erer
m         rtrt
f         tyty
```

query used is:

```
select gender, name from profile inner join e on profile.emp = e.emp
```

Now I have to write a subquery to create a table to count number of employees from particular gender like:

```
gender  count
m        3
f        2
```

With the query I wrote:

```
SELECT COUNT(gender) AS 'Count' FROM (select gender, name from profile inner join e on profile.emp = e.emp)AS Gender GROUP BY Gender;
```

I am able to print:

```
count
3
2
```

but not the gender column. How can I use join and subquery to properly display the data as required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code given below=>

```
SELECT Gender, COUNT(gender) AS 'Count' FROM (select gender, name from profile inner join e on profile.emp = e.emp)AS Gender GROUP BY Gender;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `gender` in the `select`.  You can aggregate by columns and expressions that are not selected -- although that is somewhat unusual.

In your case, you don't need a subquery.  In addition, I strongly recommend table aliases:

```
select gender, count(*)
from profile p inner join
     e
     on p.emp = e.emp
group by gender;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting `gender, COUNT(gender)` ? Your query would become

```
SELECT gender, COUNT(gender) AS 'Count' FROM (select gender, name from profile inner join e on profile.emp = e.emp)AS Gender GROUP BY Gender;
```